# How to add click action to cursor in hololens

Tags: hololens

In microsoft hololens ,Added cursor to a button but unable add cursor action ,can anyone help
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

To add the ability to "click" you can do this with the Input Manager that is built into the HoloLens Toolkit.  See here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/HoloToolkit-Unity/tree/master/Assets/HoloToolkit/Input

Specifically you should add the InputManager prefab to your scene, then add to a script that is attached to an object an implementation of IInputClickHandler.  So something like this:

```
public class DoSomethingOnClick : MonoBehaviour, IInputClickHandler
{
     void IInputClickHandler.OnInputClicked(InputEventData eventData)
    {
         // A Click happened here, do something about it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you dont forget to have an event system in your scene.