# (Hololens) Implementing a click on the cursor

Tags: c#, hololens

So I'm currently trying to script a click action when I hover my cursor over an object. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to implement the scripts and interfaces to do so, specifically where to put InputManager and how to use/implement  IInputClickHandler in my scripts. The only answer I've found ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41689958/how-to-add-click-action-to-cursor-in-hololens)) wasn't very clear, so if anyone could help that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The answer on the Stack Overflow link you've provided uses **HoloToolkit** to implement the gesture.

Download the HoloToolkit in GitHub (https://github.com/Microsoft/HoloToolkit-Unity) and look at the samples that you will find under `/Assets/HoloToolkit-Examples` folder.

From the examples, you can look at the **ColorPicker** project and from there you can find on how they implement the `IInputClickHandler` interface

Keep in mind that if you want to use the **scripts** available in the **HoloToolkit**, you need to import it first by opening your **Unity Project** and go to `Assets -> Import Package -> Custom Package` then select the HoloToolkit that you've downloaded from GitHub